# how to select all elements with matching attribute of this in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, attributes, this

I would like to select all elements within a div that have the same attribute as the selected element, using the `this` selector.

So in my example, when I click on an element with a class of `.foo`, I would like to find all elements within `.container` that share the same `data-index` attribute as the element that was clicked and then add the class of `.bah`. Currently the function I have only adds `.bah` to the element that was clicked on, I understand how to select certain attributes but not in relation to the `this` selector.

Javascript:

```
$(document).on('click','.foo', function() {
        $(this).addClass('bah');
});
```

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="inner1">
    <div data-index="0" class="foo">
      <p>item 1</p>
    </div>
    <div data-index="2" class="foo">
      <p>item 2</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="inner2">
    <div data-index="0" class="foo">
      <p>item 1</p>
    </div>
    <div data-index="2" class="foo">
      <p>item 2</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.filter()` to get the result.

```
$(document).on('click','.foo', function() {
    var dataIndex = $(this).data('index');
    $('.container div').filter(function(){
        return $(this).data('index') === dataIndex
    }).addClass('bah');
});
```

Or using attribute based selector.

```
$(document).on('click','.foo', function() {
    var dataIndex = $(this).data('index');
    $('.container div[data-index="'+dataIndex+'"]').addClass('bah');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).on('click','.foo', function() {
    var dataIndex = $(this).data('index');
    $(document).find("div[data-index='" + dataIndex + "']").each(function() {
        $(this).addClass('bah');
    });
});
```

Example Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9huw0ym9/1/